# How to change screen's color

Tags: android

I want to change screen's color as that app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vn.chicken.changecolorscreen

How to implement it. I don't have any idea for that.

I'm beginer developer android.
Thanks for your help so much.

Comment: Don't have any way set color of screen as brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Please use  `Activity.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));`

Change these values dynamically while seeking progress bar.

Comment: Thus, only this application can be colored background. I want to change screen's color as that app. That is all the screens are discolored